# What am I doing wrong with numpy searchsorted?

Tags: python, numpy, binary-search, masked-array

It's kind a funny behavior in numpy.searchsorted. The following test fail:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ma.masked_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
                        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
                        31, 32, 33, 0],
                       mask=[False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                             False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                             False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                             False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                             False, False, False, False, False,  True],
                       fill_value=0, dtype='uint8')

b = np.array([1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
              17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 33],
             dtype='uint8')

expected = np.array([0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
                 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
                 28, 29, 32])

c = a.searchsorted(b)

np.testing.assert_array_equal(c, expected)
```

The last entry in the `c` array is 34 and I don't know why. 
But a similar one, it pass:

```
aa = np.ma.masked_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0],
                        mask=[False, False, False, False, True],
                        fill_value=0, dtype='uint8')

bb = np.array([1, 3, 4], dtype='uint8')

expectedd = np.array([0, 2, 3])

cc = aa.searchsorted(bb)

np.testing.assert_array_equal(cc, expectedd)
```

On `numpy.array.searchsorted` documentation, its description said:

> Find the indices into a sorted array a such that, if the corresponding elements in v were inserted before the indices, the order of a would be preserved.

Comment: The first input `a` is not sorted because of the `zero` at the end, so you might have to use the additional input arg `sorter` with `np.searchsorted`.

Comment: @Divakar It is sorted because it is a masked array so the masked values are the last and `numpy` define this order. If you use the `argsort` method on `a` it gives you the indexes as  a ordered sequence

Comment: Hmm, yeah that I didn't consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) doesn't yet support masked arrays ([see here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html) for a list of supported methods).

You can get the expected result by manually indexing `a` with the inverse of `a.mask`, then passing the result as the first argument to `np.searchsorted`:

```
c = np.searchsorted(a[~a.mask], b)

# or alternatively, a[~a.mask].searchsorted(b)

print(np.allclose(c, expected))
# True
```

Comment: numpy support [searchsorted for Masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.searchsorted.html)

Also in the second case, with `aa`, `bb`, and `cc`, I get the expected result but the problem is with the first case.

Comment: Sorry, I initially used the wrong test case. The `.searchsorted` method is just inherited from `numpy.ndarray` - it's "not supported" in the sense that it ignores the mask.